# volumeMount subPath doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to make use of the new `subPath` feature implemented in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/22575) pull request (recently released in v1.3).

However, the output of `mount` shows it ignoring the `subPath`, mounting the same NFS directory for both volume mounts:

```
nfs-server:/mnt/nfs/exports/apps/my-app on /home/share/foo type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.128.0.4,local_lock=none,addr=nfs-server)
nfs-server:/mnt/nfs/exports/apps/my-app on /home/share/bar/baz type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.128.0.4,local_lock=none,addr=nfs-server)
```

The relevant bits of my deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: my-org/my-app:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/share/foo
          name: nfs
          subPath: foo-resources
        - mountPath: /home/share/bar/baz
          name: nfs
          subPath: baz-resources
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        nfs:
          path: /mnt/nfs/exports/apps/my-app
          server: nfs-server
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure about this, as I'm using a `configMap` volume rather than NFS, but I had to make the `mountPath` match the `subPath` as seen below before it worked for me.

FYI, I'm using Kubernetes v1.4.5.

If I'm reading this correctly, you are wanting to:

- Mount the NFS file or directory `/mnt/nfs/exports/apps/my-app/foo-resources` such that it's path in the container is `/home/share/foo/foo-resources`.
- Mount, the NFS file or directory `/mnt/nfs/exports/apps/my-app/baz-resources` such that it's path in the container is `/home/share/bar/baz/baz-resources`.

Try this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: my-org/my-app:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/share/foo/foo-resources
          name: nfs
          subPath: foo-resources
        - mountPath: /home/share/bar/baz/baz-resources
          name: nfs
          subPath: baz-resources
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        nfs:
          path: /mnt/nfs/exports/apps/my-app
          server: nfs-server
```

The differences:

```
16c16
<         - mountPath: /home/share/foo/foo-resources
---
>         - mountPath: /home/share/foo
19c19
<         - mountPath: /home/share/bar/baz/baz-resources
---
>         - mountPath: /home/share/bar/baz
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was trying to update a Kubernetes 1.4 cluster using `kubectl` version 1.2. Try updating your `kubectl` and then running `kubectl apply` on the appropriate file.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to mout to /etc/openresty/nginx.conf with subPath but it didnt worked.
Turns out that /etc/openrestry was a link to /usr/local/openresty/nginx, and I also mounter that volume as well.
So basically I was mounting with subPath to some location, and then it got overrited by a different volumeMount.